# How do I make Phaser apply changes from my game.js file?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I tried the Phaser Tutorial. I created the index.html plus a js-file called game.js.
The phaser.min.js file was downloaded too.
Everything is in the same folder.

I connected everything properly and the output works very fine but somehow Phaser doesn't recognise changes in my game.js anymore.

This is my current game.js file:

```
var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 640,
    height: 360,
    scene: {

        preload: preload,
        create: create,
        update: update
    }
};

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);

function preload(){
    this.load.image('boo', 'assets/pics/boo.png');
}

function create(){
    this.add.image(0, 0, 'boo');
}

function update(){

}
```

My index.html file looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
    <meta charset = "UFT-8">
    <meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1,
    maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
    <title> My very 1st game </title>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "phaser.min.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "game.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 0px;        
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>


</body>
</html>
```

Including the game.js file works and if I remove it from the head section it doesn't work anymore, as it should be.

If I'm going to change let's say `width: 640` to `width: 200` for example and I refresh the localhost-page, it doesn't apply the change.
If I inspect the page, the old file with `width: 360` is still used, even though it doesn't exist anymore.

It applies changes if I put the code from the game.js file into the body of index.html. It doesn't by including the game.js file.

I use XAMPP including the Apache Webserver.

Any hints what I can try? Anything will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caching. I refreshed the game with `ctrl+F5` and it applied changes.

Adding following code might help too:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache">
```